# WPF conditional binding fail after set value of bound control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 3 WPF user controls in the same grid, one is like a radio button group with two radio buttons, the other two are like TextBox. My purpose is: if the first radio button is selected, allow user to input in TextBox1, if the second radio button is selected, disable user input in TextBox1 and bind its Text property to TextBox2.Text. I have used datatriggers to achieve that. The XAML sample of bound control is like below:

```
<my:TextControl Name="TextControl1">
        <my:TextControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:TextControl}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyRadioButtons1, Path=IsFirstRadioButtonChecked}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyRadioButtons1, Path=IsSecondRadioButtonChecked}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=TextControl2, Path=Text}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </my:TextControl.Style>
    </my:TextControl>
```

I tested my code and it worked as expected at first point. Then I select first radio button, type something in TextControl1, and select second radio button. Boom....but nothing happened. The value in TextControl1 is still the text I typed instead of Text of TextControl2. It seems that TextControl1 cannot bind to TextControl2 any more whatever option I select in the radio button group. Anyone has idea about this situation??THX

Comment: You probably need to change your bindings to `RelativeSource`.

Comment: Agree with @Okuma.Scott  and if its not help one more thing u can do is  you can set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged